# Non-scrolling WRAP_CONTENT RecyclerView inside ScrollView in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I want to document the problems I ran into and the solution for the benefit of others, and find help with the key flaw in my solution.

I want a `RecyclerView` with an arbitrary number of rows in a layout with a number of other Views. The `RecyclerView` and other `View`s should be in a `ScrollView` that scrolls, but the `RecyclerView` itself should not scroll.

Since the number of rows in the `RecyclerView` is unknown, and I'm required to have other views immediately underneath the `RecyclerView`, I can't use a fixed height or `match_parent`.

I experienced some odd problems: when I would update the `RecyclerView` data (using an `AsyncListDiffer`) and the UI was supposed to update, the entire `RecyclerView` would jump above the view it was constrained underneath, straight to the top of the parent. This is not how a `ConstraintLayout` is supposed to behave.

Then I was able to stop that from happening, but `View`s underneath the `RecyclerView` would disappear--appearing once the `RecyclerView` data updated.

The solution:

1. Put the `RecyclerView` and other `View`s inside a `ConstraintLayout` inside a `ScrollView` (or `NestedScrollView`)
2. Set the `RecyclerView` to have a height of `wrap_content` (and adding `app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"` doesn't hurt)
3. Make sure the rows in the RecyclerView **have a fixed height** and do not have a height of `wrap_content`

This was helpful to me after banging my head against the wall and trying some proposed solutions that did not work: [make RecyclerView's height to "wrap_content" in Constraint layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42762494/make-recyclerviews-height-to-wrap-content-in-constraint-layout#comment84040171_42762605)

This solution is pretty simple. The layout can be something like:

```
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <!-- other Views -->

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/otherView"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/anotherView"
                />

                <!-- other Views -->
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

And then the layout for a row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                                   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                                   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                                   android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
                                                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                   android:layout_height="?attr/listPreferredItemHeight">

<!-- other views -->

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here's the problem: I'm not a fan of fixed-height rows. What if other content needs to go in there? What if the user changes their text size? I much prefer flexible layouts that can adapt in size. But if I do that, then the `RecyclerView` takes up a screen's worth of height inside the ScrollView, shoving all lower views off the bottom of the screen, no matter how few rows it contains.

The alternatives I can think of are to make all the other `View`s outside the `RecyclerView` become rows of the `RecyclerView`, or to avoid a `RecyclerView` altogether and programmatically add `View`s to a `LinearLayout`. These are much uglier approaches.

Is there a way to fix it so the rows of the `RecyclerView` can have a height of `wrap_content`?

Comment: The solution I always use for such case is recycler view with different view types. Why ugly?

Comment: note: if you set `android:layout_height="0dp"` on your ScrollView, then you should set `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"`, and if you don't then your scrollview will never be visible because it will always be 0dp height unless you constraint the Top and Bottom. I'm upvoting your question/answer because it helped me solve the same issue. thanks. concerning rows in recyclerviews, I don't use contraint layouts for that, usually I use Relative or LinearLayouts with height to wrap_content.
other note: I use `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"` on recyclerview to fix the scroll.