# Placing horizontal recyclerview at a specific position using ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-support-library, android-constraintlayout

I want to place my horizonatl recyclerview at 30% screen width from start

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        android:paddingEnd="20dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/guideline" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.3" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

But it is not recyclerview not appearing on screen working any idea how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You never gave your recyclerView a vertical constraint so what happened is that at the run time your recyclerView just jumped to the top of the screen.
**When I copied your code I saw this error:**

> This view is not constrained vertically: at runtime, it will jump to the top unless you add a vertical constraint

Some tip - if you see the red line on your view in the XML/the red warning button from the design you should really look at the error and change your layout accordingly.

And of course, I won't leave you without a good working layout - here is the layout that I made for the recyclerView to start at 30% of the screen, I have checked it and its working. (i was working with androidx but just change it to the support library if you want)

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.3"/>

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.506"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
```

Comment: not working for me I want height wrap_content for recyclerview

Comment: And when you change your height  to wrap_content , do you not see your view?

Comment: And do you have items in your recyclerView? or currently nothing? anyway try to look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49793274/8274756) explaining wrap content in recyclerVIew

Answer (score 0):

Remove the ConstraintLayout and use Linearlayout instead, than use the `android:weight=` property accordingly in both guideline and RecyclerView.

Comment: Hey Bhavik Parmar, I already posted a working example with constraint layout below, please do not disqualify constraint layout - it is a great and easy tool to learn and it gives you the option to support different screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

your `RecyclerView` is missing the vertical constraints; Add at least one so that the view can be rendered.

constrained to top:

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
```

if you want it to use the whole parent, add these too:

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```

Comment: not working for me I want height wrap_content for recyclerview

Comment: I think this answer may help you better https://stackoverflow.com/a/42762605/2811504 ;

Answer (score 0):

This will work fine for you

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        android:paddingEnd="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
       app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".3" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: There are already 2 answers that are very similar to yours, could it be that you misunderstood the question? you placed horizontally Guideline and not vertical as he asked for.